# How to semi-splay a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
void access(T elem)
```

This function should determine whether the given element is in the tree. If so, the tree should semi-splay so that the node with the given element is moved towards the root of the tree when the function returns. If the given element is not found in the tree, it should simply be inserted into the tree (with no splaying).

Here is Node class

```
public class Node<T> {
public T elem = null;
public Node<T> left = null;
public Node<T> right = null;

public Node(T _elem) {
    elem = _elem;
}

public String toString() {
    String out = elem.toString();
    out += " [L: "+ (left == null ? "null" : left.elem) + "] ";
    out += " [R: "+ (right == null ? "null" : right.elem) + "] ";
    return out;
}
```

}

Comment: We are allowed to add helper functions

Comment: A. What is your question ?  B. What did you try ? C. Explain "moved towards the root of the tree" - you mean the nodes "above" should be discarded ?